# Condition rendering of components on BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Inside my App.js I have the following function:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Alerts />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            <Route path="/:folderName" component={Business} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What I want to do is to render the  component, only on the first 4 routes, not in the /:folderName route.
I could place the Header inside each of the Landing, Signup, Login and Profile routes, but I feel there must be a better approach. I also could use render= instead of component= like so:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => (
                  <Fragment>
                    <Header />
                    <Landing />
                  </Fragment>
                )}
/>
```

But is there a better approach? Can I have a condition for the Header in the  to be rendered?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a HOC named withHeader.
Take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: Thanks @AntonioPangallo, your answer really did work best. I'll post an official answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Antonio Pangallo suggesting to use HOCs really did work best. Here's what my Switch looks like now:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={withHeaderAndAlerts(Landing)} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={withHeaderAndAlerts(Signup)} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={withHeaderAndAlerts(Login)} />
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={withHeaderAndAlerts(Profile)} />
            <Route path="/:folderName" component={Business} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the function to wrap the components with the Header and Alerts:

```
//HOC to wrap component in the Header and Alerts components
function withHeaderAndAlerts(WrappedComponent) {
  class withHeaderAndAlerts extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <Header />
          <Alerts />
          <WrappedComponent />
        </Fragment>
      );
    }
  }

  withHeaderAndAlerts.displayName = `withHeaderAndAlerts(${getDisplayName(WrappedComponent)})`;
  return withHeaderAndAlerts;
}

function getDisplayName(WrappedComponent) {
  return WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name || "Component";
}
```

Thanks Antonio!